# Using COUNTIFs with multiple date conditions and multiple ORs

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to generate foster dog/cat reports for a pet rescue organization.  They collect date_pickedup and date_returned for each foster animal and want historical monthly reports.

I need to cover the following scenarios

- animal picked up and returned in reporting month
- animal picked up in the prior month, returned in reporting month
- animal picked up in the prior month and not returned yet
- picked up in the reporting month, not returned yet

After unsuccessfully trying to create a filtered view for each month, I am now focused on calculating each month's totals using COUNTIFs on a separate tab in the google sheet

```
=countIFS ('Animal tracking'!G4:G499,">1/31/19",'Animal tracking'!H4:H499,"<=2/28/19") 

+countIFS ('Animal tracking'!G4:G499,"<=1/31/19",'Animal tracking'!H4:H499,"<=2/28/19")

+countIFS ('Animal tracking'!G4:G499,"<=1/31/19",'Animal tracking'!H4:H499,">=3/1/19")

+countIFS ('Animal tracking'!G4:G499,">1/31/19",'Animal tracking'!H4:H499,">=3/1/19")
```

I am over-counting the results, as my logic for the 4th scenario is incorrect as it returns animals that were fostered in the current month

Comment: thanks - here it is:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u4kKYhWw8nz5B3DeC2ckZPXOd1jdB4uvfX-hMAVavbw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Where you say "the prior month" you actually mean only the one prior month, yes? Not "any earlier month"?  Also, an example in your spreadsheet of accurate desired output, right where it should be, would greatly help us help you. Add a label denoting something like "I want THESE cell automatic". And explain clearly how you manually calculated them.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I mean "any earlier month".  I added in the desired output section with labels as you suggest. Thank you very much

Comment: Note. In my proposed answer, my calculations agree with yours for Feb 2019 (18 animals) but not March 2019 (you:49, me:51). It should prove a handy way to test one approach against the other.

Answer (score 0):

Your plan is to use a series of `COUNTIFS` formula on a helper sheet to calculate the historical monthly report. In my view, this specific approach won't work mainly because the proposed formula is too complex and `COUNTIFS` does not deliver the data required.

The four-tier two-stage criteria requires more detailed analysis. It's also essential to remove hard-coded dates from the formula (the same would have applied to `countifs`), and to define user-defined reporting-period dates to which the formula can be linked.

**Suggested layout**

---

[image: Criterion totals]

---

- The reporting period is defined.

  - **only one cell requires manual data entry** - the first day of the reporting period.
  - the last day of the reporting period is calculated using the `eomonth()` formula.
- Each of the four criteria is assessed separately and, within each criterion, both of the stages (Pickup date, Return date) is considered separately.
- The formulas in the stage cells are designed to yield a TRUE/FALSE answer.
- A third column ("Match") is added for each criterion to assess the stage results; if both stages yield TRUE, then (and only then) "Match" yields TRUE.
- At the top of each "Match" column, a `countif` counts the cells equal to "TRUE". The result is the number of animals for which each criterion applied during the reporting period.
- The sum of the "Match" count is the total number animals for the reporting period.

The data formulas (row#6 and below) can simply be copied down as far as required.

**Assumptions**

1. Cells M1 and N1 MUST be formatted as dates
2. Data starts row#6 and ends before row#300 (though obviously this can be changed).
3. Pickup date = Column G
4. Return Date = Column H
5. Highlighting of "TRUE" cells in the "Match" columns is for information only; done with Conditional formatting.

**Cell contents and formulas**

M1: Reporting Month (Start)         `Manual data entry`
N1: Reporting Month (END)           `=eomonth(M1,0)`

M3: Animal Count - Reporting Month  `=sum(O3:Z3)`
Q3: Total Criteria#1                `=countif(Q6:Q300,TRUE)`
T3: Total Criteria#2                `=countif(T6:T300,TRUE)`
W3: Total Criteria#3                `=countif(W6:W300,TRUE)`
Z3: Total Criteria#4                `=countif(Z6:Z300,TRUE)`

Q4: Proof#1                         `=COUNTA(Q6:Q300)-countif(Q6:Q300,FALSE)-Q3`
T4: Proof#2                         `=COUNTA(T6:T300)-countif(T6:T300,FALSE)-T4`
W4: Proof#3                         `=COUNTA(W6:W300)-countif(W6:W300,FALSE)-W5`
Z4: Proof#4                         `=COUNTA(Z6:Z300)-countif(Z6:Z300,FALSE)-Z6`

O6: P/Up#1                          `=and(G6>=$M$1,G6<=$N$1)`
P6: Rtn#1                           `=and(G6>=$M$1,G6<=$N$1)`
Q6: Match#1                         `=And(O6=TRUE,P6=TRUE)`
R6: P/Up#2                          `=G6<$M$1`
S6: Rtn#2                           `=and(H6>=$M$1,H6<=$N$1)`
T6: Match#2                         `=And(R6=TRUE,S6=TRUE)`
U6: P/Up#3                          `=G6<$M$1`
V6: Rtn#3                           `=or(H6>$N$1,isblank(H6))`
W6: Match#3                         `=And(U6=TRUE,V6=TRUE)`
X6: P/Up#4                          `=and(G6>=$M$1,G6<=$N$1)`
Y6: Rtn#4                           `=or(H6>$N$1,isblank(H6))`
Z6: Match#4                         `=And(X6=TRUE,Y6=TRUE)`